# using gprof and boost

Tags: c++, boost, gprof

While profiling a bit of code that use's many boost functions with gprof, there is a very nasty and hard to follow output see sample below , is there any way to clean up gprof for use with boost or more boost friendly alternatives? from the looks of it there is a repition of boost::math::policy that is cluttering up the profiling output making it difficult to see or understand the call graph

btw heres the a snippet of an example

```
boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy> >(long double, long double, long double*, long double*, int, boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy> const&)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will very much prefer [callgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html) to gprof. It's part of [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), so you probably already have it. You can use [kcachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html) to view the results graphically.

Comment: valgrind compiles ! now for QT